# How to get some elements from array which contain some specific text and dont duplicate it?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have an array of file paths and I want to create array that contains only uniqe files in paths_after array. Files is always starting at "OpenShop_".

Example: C:\aaa\OpenShop_F.dll; C:\aaa\vvv\OpenShop_F.dll; C:\aaa\OpenShop_E.dll

I have that code:

```
string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "OpenShop*.dll",SearchOption.AllDirectories);            
string[] endpaths;
endpaths = paths.Where(x=>Path.GetFileName(x).Contains("OpenShop_")).Distinct().ToArray();
```

I want to in endpaths array elements with unique filenames: c:\aaa\OpenShop_F.dll
c:\aaa\OpenShop_E.dll

And I have result: 
[image: Result]

I dont want the same dll's. I want only one OpenShop_Firefox.dll only one Chrome and only one IE.

Comment: this is not a valid C# syntax. it looks like php.

Comment: What is *unique files* with *uniqe paths in paths_after array*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
var endpaths = paths.Where(x=>Path.GetFileName(x).Contains("open_"))
                    .Select(x=>Path.GetFileName(x))
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToArray();
```

We use the `Path.GetFileName` to get the filename from the path `x`. For further documentation about this, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx). Then we see if the desired path is contained in the path we get. Last we get the distinct paths and convert the resutl to an array.

Comment: In this solution I have not got uniques file paths. I have:
"c:/vvv/open__shop.dll
c:/vvv/ggg/open__shop.dll"
 I want only one "open_shop.dll" file.

Comment: Why not? I suppose that as a file path you declare something like this c:/vvv/open__shop.dll. Correct?

Comment: Please try the updated one and let me know. That you are looking for is not unique paths but unique filenames.

Comment: Yes, unique filenames. I badly explain it. I'm trying this solution.

Comment: Not a problem dude. Please just try it and let me know. Thanks

Comment: This with Select not work in my program, can not convert bool to string. I edited question ;) I think its now more clearly.

Comment: I guess he wants to find all duplicates by file name, and then remove all of them but one (random). Distinct won't work as all "duplicates" contain different directories.

Comment: @user3486978 `Path.GetFileName(x)` will the filename of the path `x`. So after we have filtered paths to get the desired ones, then we get the filenames and last we get the dinstict on this collection.

Comment: Okey thanks, it isnt have all path but I will solve individually that problem.